# How to restrict simultaneous login for IBM Content Navigator

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

Due to business policies we need to restrict users to login with the same id from different stations, it will be ideal that if the user is already logged in and tries to login from another computer gets a denied message. I understand that Filenet uses JAAS to authenticate users against an LDAP provider, in our case Content Navigator is deployed on WebSphere 8.5.5.9, could it be that this already solved at that level? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This would be hard to achieve without some sort of a Single Sign-On provider where a duplicate login would void the previous ticket.

Answer (score 0):

One pur java solution is that you can try to customize the navigator WAR itself adding a Servlet Filter that:

1. **Reads the incoming request**, extracts the username, and the sessionID
2. **Checks** against a "custom table" you make whether the **username** trying to login **exists** as a record:

   2.1: **If exists**, check the session ID, **If the same** pass the request, **otherwise deny access**.

   2.2: **If doesn't exist**, **add** the username and the session ID to the **table**, and **allow access**.

There might be other ways, but you got to remember that in the end, navigator is just another web app that you can manipulate using JEE.